# Change color of ToolBarItem in XAML

Tags: xaml, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, mobile-development

I've added a toolbaritem in my app, however i dont see a way to change its background and text color.

```
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>

    <ToolbarItem Text="About" 
                 Icon="ic_action_more_vert.png"
                 Priority="0"
                 Order="Secondary"
                 Clicked="ToolbarItem_Clicked"/>

    <ToolbarItem Text="Settings"
                 Icon="ic_action_more_vert.png"
                 Priority="0"
                 Order="Secondary"/>

</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

This is what I'd like changed. The black menu with white text, want to change that bg color and text color. Any idea how to achieve this?

[image]

Comment: I think you will have to do this by Android styling/theming

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As @Gerald Versluis suggested, you can do this by Android styling.

Firstly you can find the `styles.xml` file under the values folder of `Resources` in Android project:

[image]

Inside of this file, you can open this file and create a style for your menu like this:

```
<style name="AppToolbarTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
  <item name="android:colorBackground">#2196F3</item>
  <item name="android:textColor">#000080</item>
</style>
```

Then open the `Toolbar.axml` in android project

[image]

and change the `app:popupTheme` of `Toolbar` like this:

```
app:popupTheme="@style/AppToolbarTheme"
```

**Update:**

Here is the code of `Toolbar`:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppToolbarTheme" />
```

Comment: @Curiousity, are you using XF for development? What is the version?

Comment: Yes I'm using XF. Version - 4.5

Comment: @Curiousity, version 4.5? By my side the latest version is 2.3.4.247, try to clean and rebuild your project, if problem still exists,  show me your styles.xml.

Comment: Very sorry. My mistake. The version is 2.3.4.247. Same as yours. And I tried cleaning and rebuilding the project several times. May be I'm missing something. But I did as above.

Comment: @Curiousity, can you please show me all code of your styles.xml and toolbar.axml? Or try to create a new project and this code again.

Comment: Hi @GraceFeng-MSFT , how do i change the code in Toolbar.axml? currently it shows a blank phone screen with no code :/

Comment: @Unicorn_Girl, you can right click on it and open with "XML (Text) Editor", if you double click on this file, then in the down-left side of screen, click the `Source` button.

Comment: @GraceFeng-MSFT, Im getting this error -   the "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:popupTheme" attribute is not declared. 

In my toolbar.axml , I have this:  android:popupTheme="@style/AppToolBarTheme" />

and in styles.xml I have this: 
<style name="AppToolBarTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:colorBackground">#0a9dbd</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#000080</item>"
    
  </style>

Comment: @Unicorn_Girl, change `android:popupTheme` to `app:popupTheme`, actually by default there is the theme defined for this property, just change the style to the one we defined (AppToolBarTheme) in styles.xml.

Comment: @Unicorn_Girl, whatever, I edited my answer and post the whole code of `Toolbar`, you may check it.

Comment: @GraceFeng-MSFT, It is working now :D . Thanks so much

Comment: this saved my life. <3 How on earth can you discover such method like this? @GraceFeng because all the resources in XF are unlike Android Studio which can easily be discover from IntelliSense.

Comment: We are in 2021 now, and nothing helps. Android 11 SDK, Xamarin Forms 5.0.0.2196, and menu is still white on black.

Answer (score 13):

I found a solution :https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/40529/toolbaritem-textcolor

Simple add to "styles.xml":

```
<item name="android:actionMenuTextColor"> @color/orange </item>
```

I've spent hours looking for it..

Comment: Your approach totally works, however, I have a menu, page title and next. so the color being change is only the secondary which is next, page title still white.any idea?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

In **styles.xml**

`<item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">#000080</item>`

Answer (score 0):

To change first item text edit `android:theme` `android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"` or `android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"` for second item text edit popupTheme