# Xamarin forms Android toolbar text-color

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

The toolbar color is by default white and I would like to change it to blue. I was able to change almost everything but not that.

Toolbar.axml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

styles.xml

```
<style name="MyTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
       <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#1b2b32</item>
      <item name="android:textColorSecondary">#1c4d9e</item>
```

[image: logout text is always in white]

Answer (score 8):

I found an approach. it is mixed with all the answers I read out there. 
I used this answer from 
[Change color of ToolBarItem in XAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45323451/change-color-of-toolbaritem-in-xaml/50414898#comment91080810_50414898) @Guillermo Daniel Arias.
on styles.XML

```
<item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">#1c4d9e</item>
```

on App.xml (On xamarin forms share project)

```
 <Style TargetType="NavigationPage">
        <Setter Property="BarBackgroundColor" Value="White"/>
        <Setter Property="BarTextColor" Value="#004895"/>
        </Style>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There are two possible approaches:

- You change the `BarBackgroundColor` and `BarTextColor` of your `NavigationPage`. In your case, it would be something like that:

---

```
MainPage = new NavigationPage(new YourPage())
{
      BarBackgroundColor = Color.White,
      BarTextColor = Color.Blue
};
```

- The other approach is to set your Android styles. You're already doing that, but I think that's wrong. Instead of `android:textColorPrimary`android:textColorSecondary`, try something like that:

---

```
<style name="MyTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="colorSecondary">#0000FF</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#0000FF</item>
</style>
```

I think that `android:` may be the problem, because I'm doing exactly like I said and it's working.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will try the second one. keep you posted

Answer (score 0):

in App.xml add this :

```
 <Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Color x:Key="mRed">#65508F</Color>
        <Color x:Key="mWhite">#FFFFFF</Color>

        <Style TargetType="NavigationPage">
            <Setter Property="BarBackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource mRed}" />
            <Setter Property="BarTextColor" Value="{StaticResource mWhite}" />
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```