# Changing ToolbarItem text color via xaml to all platform(Android,iOS,UWP)

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, textcolor, toolbaritems

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZGju.png)This is my xaml code:

ContentPage.ToolbarItems
   ToolbarItem Text="+" Priority="0" Order="Primary" Command="{Binding PrikaziCommand}"
   ToolbarItem
ContentPage.ToolbarItems

How to change color of text through xaml code to all platform?

Comment: Please post your codebase sample.

Comment: Please refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45323451/change-color-of-toolbaritem-in-xaml

Comment: I do not see any XAML!!!!

Comment: I see that link MShah,but dont help me,need me in xaml to i can specific to all platform this is only for android,but me android works fine....I place xam code but dont see probably because tag,i edit code without tag now....

Comment: @Srki92 Why dont you use navigation.title view

Comment: We could not set the ToolbarItem text color directly in xaml because there is no such an API . The workaround is set it in specific platforms like the solution in the link .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change your toolbar textcolor, you can use **Navigation.Titleview**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TitleViewSample"
             x:Class="TitleViewSample.MainPage">

      <NavigationPage.TitleView>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Label Text="Your Title" Grid.Column="0" TextColor="White" FontSize="Large" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"></Label>

            <StackLayout Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,5,5,5">
                <Label Text="?" FontSize="Large" TextColor="Red" Margin="10" ></Label>
                <Label Text="+" FontSize="Large" TextColor="Green" Margin="10" ></Label>
            </StackLayout>
        </Grid>
</NavigationPage.TitleView>


</ContentPage>
```

If you want to change the toolbar color add this code when navigating to your specific page

```
 MainPage = new NavigationPage(new YourPage());
((NavigationPage)MainPage).BarBackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#19110F");
```

[image: Result]

Comment: NavigationPage.TitleView and ContentPage.ToolbarItems are two different things.ContentPage.ToolbarItems dont have TextColor....

Comment: yes. You can use NavigationPage.TitleView instead of contentpage.Toolbar items

Comment: When i try to place 2 label tag in NavigationPage.TitleView ,C# said that the property'TitleView' is set more than once.

Comment: @Srki92 What items do you want to be in your toolabr?

Comment: @Srki92  I edited my answer. You should place your controls inside a stacklayout or frame

Comment: I try with stack layout in title view,but still same mistake.And that solution to place in Navigation page title view dont solution for me because i must place it with horizontal placement 2 iteams.With Toolbar iteams i dont worry to placement 2 iteams.I want to place ? sign for inromation,and + for search iteam,but i have problem with UWP platform ,item dont see because is white on default,that i want to change on something other color to be visible....

Comment: Can you post your xaml

Comment: If you want to change the toolbar color, MainPage = new NavigationPage(new Page1())
    {
        BarBackgroundColor = Color.Gray
    };

Comment: i add screenshot image on first question on the top.

Comment: @Srki92 Please check my updated answer. You can use image at the place of labels

Comment: its worked thank you,i try your solution with NavigationPage.TitleView,but i have another problem when implement that,i must be carefull with image size...and that is bigger job...

Comment: @Srki92 Glad it helped. Can you accept this answer?

Comment: @Srki92 You should use height request and widthrequest of image as 30